# Place portlet under dockbar

Tags: liferay, portlet

I want to do a greetings portlet that will say: **Good morning, %username% (Logout)**. I don't want to place it on dockbar (there is a limit of max characters count per dockbar child and i don't know how to remove that limitation), i want to place it under the dockbar (like in attached picture).

[image: Greetings]

Is it possible? If not - how can i remove limit of max characters in dockbar child?
Using Liferay 6.2.

Comment: I didn't get the `limit of max characters` part. Pardon my naivete but can you explain that in a little detail? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use theme.

You can modify the `portal_normal.vm` and [embed your portlet](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/embedding-portlets-in-themes-on-liferay) in theme just like liferay is accessing the dockbar portlet.

Add some custom styles for positioning the portlet and you are good to go.